# Modify user table search results

Tags: wp-user-query

Hi i am using the following to modify the results returned from a search on the users tables in wp admin :

```
add_action('pre_get_users','custom_user_search');

 $query->query_vars['meta_query'] = array(
'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'billing_postcode',
        'value' => str_replace('*', '',  $query->query_vars['search']),
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
```

);

This returns the expected results on a standard table load, but when not in conjunction with a search returns an empty set.  Can someone explain why this?

Comment: "Does not work" means the action doesn't get triggered, or you are not receiving the results you expected? Does `$query->request` show the correct SQL?

Answer (score 1):

OK, Here's how I did it :

```
add_action('pre_user_query', 'custom_user_list_queries');

function custom_user_list_queries($query){ 

if(!empty($query->query_vars['search'])) {
    $query->query_from .= "  LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_usermeta AS alias ON (wp_users.ID = alias.user_id)";//note use of alias
    $query->query_where .= " OR ".
          "(alias.meta_key = 'billing_postcode' AND alias.meta_value LIKE '%".$query->query_vars['search']."%') ".
          " OR ".
          "(alias.meta_key = 'first_name' AND alias.meta_value LIKE '%".$query->query_vars['search']."%') ".
          " OR ".
          "(alias.meta_key = 'last_name' AND alias.meta_value LIKE '%".$query->query_vars['search']."%') ".
          " OR ".
          "(alias.meta_key = 'chat_name' AND alias.meta_value LIKE '%".$query->query_vars['search']."%') ";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query built in this way will search for users by their standard properties `AND` by this meta field. You want to probably use `OR` instead of `AND`.

To debug query results try to find out what SQL it produce.

```
function wpse_289735_debug_user_query( $query ) {

    echo "SELECT $query->query_fields $query->query_from $query->query_where $query->query_orderby $query->query_limit";
    die();
}

add_filter('pre_user_query', 'wpse_289735_debug_user_query');
```

I could not find any hook which will allow you to modify query to your needs so I crated simple class which will replace SQL directly.

```
class WPSE_289735_User_Search {

    /**
     * Search phrase
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $search;

    /**
     * Class constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->define_hooks();
    }

    /**
     * Filter used to save search phrase and add filter which will replace SQL
     */
    public function add_custom_search_filter( $query ) {

        if( isset( $query->query_vars['search'] ) && !empty( $query->query_vars['search'] ) ) {

            /**
             * Save search phrase
             */
            $this->search = str_replace('*', '', $query->query_vars['search']);

            /**
             * Add filter only when searching users
             */
            add_filter( 'query', array($this, 'replace_user_search_sql') );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Replace user search SQL with own SQL
     */
    public function replace_user_search_sql( $query ) {

        /**
         * Immediately remove filter to not break other queries
         */
        remove_filter( 'query', array($this, 'replace_user_search_sql') );

        global $wpdb;

        $sql[] = "SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS $wpdb->users.ID";
        $sql[] = "FROM $wpdb->users";
        $sql[] = "INNER JOIN $wpdb->usermeta ON ($wpdb->users.ID = $wpdb->usermeta.user_id)";

        $sql[] = "WHERE 1=1";

        $sql[] = "AND";
        $sql[] = "(";
        $sql[] =     "($wpdb->usermeta.meta_key = 'billing_postcode' AND $wpdb->usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%s')";
        $sql[] =     "OR";
        $sql[] =     "($wpdb->users.user_login LIKE '%s' OR $wpdb->users.user_url LIKE '%s' OR $wpdb->users.user_email LIKE '%s' OR $wpdb->users.user_nicename LIKE '%s' OR $wpdb->users.display_name LIKE '%s')";
        $sql[] = ")";

        $sql[] = "ORDER BY $wpdb->users.user_login ASC LIMIT 0, 20";

        return $wpdb->prepare( join(" ", $sql), $this->search, $this->search, $this->search, $this->search, $this->search, $this->search );
    }

    /**
     * Define plugin related hooks
     */
    private function define_hooks() {

        /**
         * Filter used to save search phrase and add filter which will replace SQL
         */
        add_action('pre_get_users', array( $this, 'add_custom_search_filter'));
    }
}

new WPSE_289735_User_Search();
```

Comment: Could i have some usage instructions or will this run out of the box?

Comment: This will run out of the box. It is working only for your meta key ‘billing_postcode’.

Comment: No, it is not working, just returns an empty set.

Comment: Echo ‘$wpdb->prepare’ output and play with SQL in phpmyadmin. I tested this code, there must be some issue with naming or data structure.